# How to integrate C++ file into Android Application using JNI

Tags: android

I want to use C++ file in my android application via JNI but i don't know how to integrate C++  file and how to Compile and run it.

Please help me if anybody knows about it

Comment: AFAIK, Android has its own virtual machine http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29 which is not the Oracle/Sun JVM so JNI is not the right glue for it.

Comment: Download android ndk from http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html It includes example projects that show how to use the NDK.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do NDK programming. [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

The Android NDK is a toolset that lets you embed components that make use of native code in your Android applications.

Android applications run in the Dalvik virtual machine. The NDK allows you to implement parts of your applications using native-code languages such as C and C++. This can provide benefits to certain classes of applications, in the form of reuse of existing code and in some cases increased speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Android NDK for your requirements.

[Android-NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

The **NDK** is a toolset that allows you to implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as C and C++. For certain types of apps, this can be helpful so that you may reuse existing code libraries written in these languages and possibly increased performance.

Tutorial [Advanced Android: Getting Started with the NDK](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/)

Using Android NDK create shared library of your C,C++ files and load that library at runtime from your Android application. Look at tutorial I linked.